# MySQL: a simple regexp not working as expected

Tags: mysql, regex

In a field of a MySQL table, I have to recognize when content is of the form `dd/mm/yyyy`, in order to reformat it in proper SQL form like `yyyy-mm-dd`.

It didn't work so I tried testing in this simple form:

```
SELECT "23/01/2002" REGEXP "^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$"
```

which returns the following:

```
"23/01/2002" REGEXP "^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$" -> 0
```

I'm probably missing something obvious...

Comment: You are not using MySQL v8. So `\d` doesn't work. Try `"^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$"` instead.

Comment: *"Try "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$" instead. "* @ravo see danblack's answer, it makes more sense then using regex for this problem. as it also can use a [index](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/45bKxK4ATcoXf57insD7NN/1) if one is there or is needed for searching.

Comment: @revo Wow: I didn't know that something so common didn't work with old versions of MySQL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using regex, use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) using a format string for the date. In your case:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(col, "%d/%m/%Y") FROM table
```

If this doesn't parse, it will be `NULL`

Comment: @cFreed indeed `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('23/01/2002', '%d/%m/%Y') IS NOT NULL` would make more sense to use then using regex as you are dealing with dates

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. Rather ironically, `STR_TO_DATE` is what I'm using in the real work, to update field with the right format, but didn't think to it for the WHERE clause.